# App Engine version served by "default" appears to be inconsistent and thrash for a period after changing the default version

Tags: google-app-engine

Our application serves an endpoint which simply reports os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID']. We use this for a type of monitoring which tracks which version is currently set as the "default version".

Starting on the afternoon of March 5th, we noticed odd behaviour when making requests to this endpoint. Shortly after we change the default version (via "appcfg.py set_default_version"), repeated requests to this endpoint would flip flop between the previous default and the new default. This persists for a period of about 10 minutes, after which point all subsequent requests will always report the new, correct default version. So it appears as if during this 10 minute window, requests to our normal, default URL, will inconsistently report either the old version or the new one.

This appears to be a change in behaviour. The previous change in default version for our application happened on March 1st, and every other version change prior to that date did not exhibit this flip-flopping behaviour.

(Question stolen from [my teammate](https://plus.google.com/110287455381476170305/about)'s [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8970))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First a bit of background:

- App Engine runs your application in distributed infrastructure: the more traffic your app receives, the more instances (appservers) that will be running your code at any given time
- For scalability/simplicity and many other reasons, App Engine does not implement client <-> appserver stickiness; as a result any request to the default app version may be handled by any appserver

After changing the default version of your application, either by changing what version is marked as the default via the admin console, or by deploying the same major version as is currently the default, information about this change is propagated through the App Engine infrastructure. As appservers become aware of the new version, they begin loading the new version of your application code. Once a given appserver is ready it will begin serving the new version of your code.

There is some period of time during which some appservers will be serving the previous default version while others are already serving the new default version. It is therefore expected that any app with a non-trivial amount of traffic will see the behavior you described.

We're always working on ways to reduce the amount of time these version changes take, but our foremost concern is to ensure that the transition happens smoothly. If the application has a large number of instances serving the previous version, App Engine needs to ensure that there is always sufficient capacity (combing old and new appservers) to serve all current traffic. The previous and new versions of the app may need a different number of appservers (due to performance differences between versions), which is another reason why the transition cannot safely be executed 'instantly'.

If you'd like more control over the process, you can use App Engine's [Traffic Splitting](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/trafficsplitting) feature. In a step wise fashion you can increase the percentage of user traffic you'd like to direct at the new version. App Engine will then provide version stickiness based on either client IP address or a cookie (for web apps). You can also use Traffic Splitting to 'canary' a new version of the application on some percentage (say 1%) of clients.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Fred. The behavior you describe is what I would expect from a large system like GAE. What puzzles me is why we never saw this behavior prior to March 5. Prior to that deploy, all changes to default appeared to happen "atomically" for us, so it seems like something changed. Not sure whether or not you can confirm that for us, but it's good to get confirmation that this is at least intended behavior going forward

Comment: Any chance you were hitting an App Engine 'backend' as opposed to a frontend instance? Have you used Traffic Splitting at any point in the past? There are several variable that might impact what version you'd see from request to request. However, the behavior you're describing is expected, and definitely something that I've seen before. I should also note that we do continue to improve and make changes to the App Engine scheduler, so a change in observed behavior when probing in a particular way is not entirely unexpected, although I can't easily explain why you didn't see this before.

Comment: @FredSauer: No, we've definitely been hitting frontends this whole time. At one point we managed to accidentally turn on Traffic Splitting but I don't believe we ever configured it to do anything other than pass 100% of traffic to a single version; we turned it off because having it on seems to disable the frontend cache. As far as we know we haven't changed anything that would cause it to have this behavior.

Comment: Just to add some data to @beekay's observations: the "period of time during which some appservers will be serving the previous default version" is lasting up to and over 15 minutes for us as of recently. Would this be expected?

Comment: @FredSauer What is a reasonable amount of time to assume that, once past, all requests will be served by the new default version?  Today we saw the old version hanging around for ~1 hr.  Is this a function of number of instances? Is there anything we can do to speed it up?

Comment: @FredSauer we also see old default versions staying around ("sticky") for around 30+ minutes after a new version is deployed. So sometimes new client side code tries to call new API endpoints but the request ends up at an older version which doesn't have that endpoint yet.

I understand that we can do some things to make our deployments more backwards compatible (like deploying new endpoints without using them until the version is fully rolled out or having the client retry several times until it hits a new version …) but the deployment situation was way easier before the March 5 change.

Comment: Another data point: I'm seeing older, non-default versions of my app still running (and being restarted) over 30 hours after having designated a more recent version as the default. Is this expected?