# How to use Cloud Endpoints in combination with App Engine's Traffic Splitting?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

From the observations I have seen from our application App Engine only provides the endpoints from the version which is set as default. When we deploy a new version including a new endpoint it's not available for clients when using Traffic Splitting.

Comment: This is not the case, we recently added support for non-default versions. As for traffic splitting, what is the specific use case? Versioning your APIs is a much better solution than relying on traffic splitting.

Comment: We usually use Traffic Splitting feature to provide version stickiness for our customers. Fred Sauer mentioned this approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15417186/837709

Comment: What I currently do is:
-- The Application is running under version 1 is set as default. It serves a Cloud Endpoints API with the version 0_0_1.
-- Add a new API with the version 0_0_2 and add a new endpoint test.
-- Update app.yaml to version 2 and deploy
-- Turn on "Traffic Split" with 99% for version 2

Comment: My result:
I don't see the API version 0_0_2 in the API Explorer and the 0_0_2 endpoint returns a 404 response

Comment: What's the recommended way to upgrade to a new version using Cloud Endpoints?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I'd say it's very likely that traffic splitting won't accomplish what you're expecting it to. The "recommended" way is to just bump the API version (which you're doing) and call that. If it's not showing up in the APIs explorer, it's possible deployment failed? Does it show up when you reference the specific version.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your application in two steps.

1. Deploy a new version including the new endpoint not used by any client and set this version to default.
2. Deploy a new version and setup traffic splitting for you application.